# Standard Brownian Motion process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, brownian-motion

I would appreciate the help in the following

$\{x(t): 0\leq t \leq 1\}$ Standard Brownian motion.

$ t^*=\inf\{t\in[0,1]:x(t)=\underset{0\leq s \leq 1}{\sup} x(s) \}$
random variable , $\{y(t): 0\leq t \leq 1\}$ Standard Brownian motion are independent,
$ \mathbb{E}(t^*)<\infty $ then

$\mathbb{E}\left[(y(t^*))^2\right] =\mathbb{E}(t^*)$

I would like to know if this result is true and if it is true, how can I prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not really about Brownian motion.
You see, $t^*$ and $y$ are independent, which makes:
$$\mathbb{E}( y(t^*)^2 |t^*=t )= \mathbb{E}( y(t)^2 |t^*=t)= t$$
Hence forth what follows.

**P/s**: $t^*$ and $y$ are independent

Comment: Thanks for the help,  and for the last equality that was used?

Comment: Yes it is it. I think it is the most intuitive way to see the equality in yout post. p/s: There is some technical remark about the conditional expectation that i gave you but i think it is not nessessary.( because it is too pathological)